# Existe possibilidade de versionamento de arquivos que não sejam códigos?

Tags: versionamento

Como versiono arquivos do Ireport ou outra ferramenta ?

Pois trabalho com um **ERP** e preciso achar uma forma de versionar os arquivos que edito.

Comment: Está procurando por uma ferramenta ou tecnologia adequada para versionamento de arquivos binários, então? Ou precisa ser com Git mesmo?

Comment: Na realidade pode ser qualquer coisa, só preciso achar um jeito que consiga versionar isso. Se não cada vez que dou manutenção nos códigos do ERP acabo me perdendo. Seria um ERP parecido com a totvs ou SAP

Comment: Não é adequado versionar o arquivo gerado pelo `iReport` com git ou ferramentas similares. O melhor que me esbarrei até agora foi manter os `jrxml`s no versionamento e, na hora de gerar o relatório, compilá-lo programaticamente

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado ok entendido, mas e quando o sistema utiliza uma linguagem própria de programação, onde salva o arquivo como um extensão única. Devo salvar o algoritmo em um TXT e dai versionar ?

Comment: **EU** particularmente focaria em manter a parte textual original do código, no máximo um gerenciador de artefatos (que não é versionamento de código) para manter algo que tem grande custo de compilação. Não conhecendo o que você realmente precisa, quais as limitações que precisa atender, não consigo contribuir significativamente

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode versionar qualquer coisa (no git, pelo menos), inclusive formatos binários. É costumeiro incluir ativos como imagens no Git de um código-fonte, afinal são parte integrante do programa.

O que você tem de ter em mente é: formatos binários não são muito "diffáveis", ou seja, quando o arquivo mudar, o controle de versão vai armazenar uma versão nova do arquivo inteiro, e o tamanho total do repositório vai aumentar na mesma proporção. Se for um arquivo binário grande e que muda o tempo todo, isso pode ser um problema.

Geralmente se evita armazenar ativos que são produto do build/processo de compilação, pois mudam o tempo todo, não colaboram para "contar a história" do código-fonte, e podem ser gerados novamente sempre que necessário.

Essa regra **não é escrita em pedra** – pode ser que a geração do ativo dependa de uma ferramenta especial que só esteja instalada numa máquina por questões de licença, ou seja muito demorado gerar, ou dependa de uma máquina configurada especialmente para a tarefa. Em resumo, tem de balancear o custo de "engordar" o tamanho do repositório versus o custo de gerar novamente o ativo.

Comment: Mesmo para esses casos de limitação na geração, eu colocaria em um servidor de artefatos. Não preciso controlar fonte, apenas um binário afinal. Uma ideia que eu já vi foi servir através do Jenkins esses artefatos gerados e fazer o download na hora do empacotamento. Outro uso bizarro foi forçar goela abaixo do Artifactory um artefato abstrato numa versão arbitrária.

Comment: É uma opção, colocar ativos pesados num servidor separado. Não coloquei na resposta por brevidade, mas é uma boa ideia, e bastante usada, mesmo.

Answer (score 1):

Sim, é possível.

Vejo que você está procurando uma solução com relação ao versionamento de relatórios do Jasper.

Procurei na internet e encontrei um [procedimento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295241/how-to-use-version-control-with-jasperreports) que pode ser útil para você, caso a sua intenção seja utilizar o versionamento para promover um desenvolvimento integrado entre membros de uma equipe:

- Após finalizar o expediente de desenvolvimento, exporte todos os relatórios do projeto para uma pasta que esteja com controle de versão;
- Faça o commit e envie para o remoto;
- Antes de retornar às atividades, sincronize a sua pasta com o código do remoto e importe o projeto novamente para o Jasper;
- Continue o desenvolvimento.

Comment: Isso dá certo, até o momento que não dará mais. Já passei por problemas demais em projeto que usava esse esquema, inclusive bugs que não apareciam quando estávamos depurando porque o compilado não batia com o `jrxml`. Enquanto você não tiver um procedimento de garantia automática disso, sua equipe estará sujeita a problemas desse tipo.